# Confirmation alert always returns true even if you Click Cancel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, alert, code-behind, confirmation

```
delete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');");
```

This code has been working fine but in my new project it always returns true even if you Click Cancel on Alert Window.

The only differnce that I know between my projects is that the new one is 4.5 .Net framwork while the others are 4.0

Working with WebForms Asp.Net

Any suggestions?

This is the code:

```
protected void gvEnterprises_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) { if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) { name = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[1].Text); var delete = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0]; delete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure to delete [" + name + "]?');"); delete.Text = "Del"; delete.Style.Add("color", "#D00000"); } }
```

Comment: try: `return (confirm('Are you sure to delete [" + name + "]?'));`

Comment: No change with that unfortunately.